# how to download php string when button is clicked

Tags: php, download, header, export-to-csv

I have read most of the SO questions related to this and I understand that I can use following to download a string as a file in PHP:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="default-filename.txt"');
echo 'string to download';
```

However my problem is a bit more. I have something like following:

```
$csvString = "";
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<div> $key has $value</div>";
  $csvString = "$key,$value\n";
}
echo "<button> Click here to download as CSV</button>";
```

As you might have already guessed, I want $csvString to be downloaded when the button is clicked. Any pointers on how I can get that done.

Comment: `<a href="download.php?id=whatever">click here</a>`

Comment: @MarcB erm....how does that work?

Comment: @UndefinedVariable I think, [this](https://www.ziplineinteractive.com/blog/proper-php-headers-for-csv-documents-all-browsers/) tutorial will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have csv.php file, then do:

```
if (isset($_GET['download'] == 1)) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="default-filename.txt"');
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key,$value\n";
    }
    exit;
}

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div> $key has $value</div>";
}

echo "<a href='csv.php?download=1'><button> Click here to download as CSV</button></a>";
```

Basically, if you want all the logic in single file, first check if download is requested and if so prepare it. If no download is request just write your html.